# Joomla: JDatabase vs direct SQL manipulation from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

Need to do some manipulation to MySQL db in Joomla 2.5.

What are pros and cons for using :

- JDatabase or
- direct SQL manipulation from PHP (with php functions: mysql_connect, mysql_select_db, mysql_query, mysql_fetch_row)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the JDatabase is the hands down winner, since you have to find the prefix of all the tables somehow.

With JDatabase, you use `#__` to automatically access the prefix of this Joomla installation. (Remember that you may have various Joomla installations on one database).

You would have to do various work-arounds to find that in other ways, or you would have to create tables without a prefix which is also a bad idea with Joomla code.

I disagree with wiscWeb. This is not a matter of different opinions. All extensions I have ever seen to the moment, use the JDatabase class or extend that class for their own functions. (and I have seen hundreds of extensions)

Comment: It is actually fairly easy to find out the db prefix; however if you are writing an extension, the more you adhere to standards (using JDatabase in this case) the easier it will be to read and extend your code.  Don't forget to quote/escape all user-provided values

Comment: You're right, they may find it from the Global Configuration options. Indeed that's not very hard - I didn't have that in mind. Although, the advantages of using JDatabase when writing for Joomla extend beyond the prefix, as you also mention.

Comment: Not to mention that if for some reason you switched to another database or you want to reuse your code for another database it will work out of the box.